# Python - IDLE syntax error problem

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, python-idle

I am using IDLE to learn python and I just notices something. Whenever I do a mistake, and press enter key, the program throws a syntax error. That's fine till now. But why I cannot go back, edit the lines and then re-run the code instead of writing again? I mean:

```
>>> def func(params):
        return ";"
if 1 + 1 == 2 """this will throw a syntax erro when I press enter"""
```

can't I just put an indent and continue to code instead of having to write the whole code again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are entering your program into an REPL - Read, Evaluate, Print Loop. As you enter lines, they are being evaluated and the output is printed.

You should write your code in a file, name it MyCode.py or whatever, and then open that with IDLE. You can then call functions inside your file from within IDLE, or execute the whole thing all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The input you have put in before is kept unchanged so you have a record of exactly what you typed and what results you got.

If you typed a line into IDLE that had a syntax error and you want to correct it, but don't want to type the whole thing again, then you should click at the end of the line and press Enter.  Then you'll get a new editable copy of the line at the bottom of the IDLE window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows I suggest using [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/). It's amazing, especially for beginners.